# Get Telerik Grid Checkbox value

Tags: checkbox, telerik, grid

I am not able to get Telerik Grid checkbox value in JQuery alert

My View Code:

```
@( Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
    columns.Bound(o => o.id)
.Template(@<text><input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#=id #>' /></text>)
  .Title("Select")
   .Width(50)
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
   columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
})
)

<p>
<button class="t-button t-state-default" onclick="displayCheckedOrders()">Display checked orders</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayCheckedOrders() {
        var $checkedRecords = $('input[name=checkedRecords]:checked');
        alert($checkedRecords[0].value);
        alert($checkedRecords[1].value);
 };
</script>
</p>
```

I have checked first two rows checkboxes and I clicked button.
In alert messgae instead of getting a value like 1, 2,3 I am getting <#=id #>

how do i get the exact binded value of checkbox in alert message

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns => 
        {
            columns.Template(o => {
            %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedRecords" value="<%= o.id %>"  />
            <%
            })
            .Title("Select")
            .Width(50)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
            columns.Bound(o => o.id);
        })
        .Render();
 %>
```

Reference: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/templatesserverside